# azure resource prive endpoint creation error

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform

I am trying to create a private endpoint for Azure Function App using terraform

The code for functionApp is

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "azure-functions-test-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "functionsapptestsa"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "azure-functions-test-service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  sku {
    tier = "PremiumContainer"
    size = "P1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "test-azure-functions"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
}
```

This all works fine, the functionapp gets created. I am trying to create private endpoint to this functionapp with following code

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "examplepe" {
  name                = "example-endpoint"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.endpoint.id  #dummy data

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "example-privateserviceconnection"
    is_manual_connection           = false
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_function_app.example.id
    subresource_names  = ["blob"]
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is " Error creating private endpoint "resource name".... failure sending request: Statuscode=0 -- Original Error: Code="BadRequest" Message="Call to Microsoft.Web/sites failed. Error message: GroupId is invalid." Details=[]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with incorrect subResource name being selected.

```
Resource Type   SubResource Name    Secondary SubResource Name
Data Lake File System Gen2  dfs dfs_secondary
Sql Database / Data Warehouse   sqlServer   
Storage Account blob    blob_secondary
Storage Account file    file_secondary
Storage Account queue   queue_secondary
Storage Account table   table_secondary
Storage Account web web_secondary
Web App / Function App  sites   
Web App / Function App Slots    sites-<slotName>
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/private_endpoint#subresource_names

This has the details of the subresource

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.